# CUnit CU_register_suites(suites) error

Tags: c, unit-testing, cunit

I'm testing this code with CUnit.
I get this error message:

> /bin/sh: line 1: 44477 Segmentation fault: 11  ./build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/tests/TestFiles/f2

Where is fault? I can't see it. Can anybody tell me why I am getting this error. 
Thanks in advance

Where is fault? I can't see it. Can anybody tell me why I am getting this error. 
Thanks in advance

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <CUnit/Basic.h>
#include <CUnit/TestDB.h>

int add(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}

int init_suite(void) {
    return 0;
}

int clean_suite(void) {
    return 0;
}

void test1() {
     CU_ASSERT(add(2, 2) == 4);
}

void test2() {
    CU_ASSERT(add(2, 3) == 5);
}

CU_TestInfo test_array1[] = {
    { "add/test1", test1},
    { "add/test2", test2},
    CU_TEST_INFO_NULL,
};


CU_TestInfo test_array2[] = {
    { "add/test3", test1},
    { "add/test4", test2},
    CU_TEST_INFO_NULL,
};


CU_SuiteInfo suites[] = {
    { "suit1", init_suite, clean_suite, test_array1},
    { "suit2", init_suite, clean_suite, test_array2},
    CU_SUITE_INFO_NULL,
};

int main() {

/* initialize the CUnit test registry */
if (CUE_SUCCESS != CU_initialize_registry())
    return CU_get_error();

/* Add a suite to the registry */
if (CUE_SUCCESS != CU_register_suites(suites)) {
    CU_cleanup_registry();
    return CU_get_error();
}

/* Run all tests using the CUnit Basic interface */
CU_basic_set_mode(CU_BRM_VERBOSE);
CU_basic_run_tests();
CU_basic_show_failures(CU_get_failure_list());
printf("\n");

CU_cleanup_registry();
return CU_get_error();
}
```

Comment: Is nobody interested? :)

Answer (score 0):

If you come across this issue on a recent cunit version, i.e. `2.1`, the segmentation fault should come from the ill-defined `CU_SuiteInfo` on your code snippet.

```cpp
CU_SuiteInfo suites[] = {
    { "suit1", init_suite, clean_suite, test_array1},
    { "suit2", init_suite, clean_suite, test_array2},
    CU_SUITE_INFO_NULL,
};
```

A [recent change](https://sourceforge.net/p/cunit/code/133/tree/trunk/CUnit/Headers/TestDB.h#l696) added two new property `pSetUpFunc` and `pTearDownFunc` to the `CU_SuiteInfo` interface, thus you have to declare your suites like

```cpp
int setup_suite(void) { return 0; }
int teardown_suite(void) { return 0; }

CU_SuiteInfo suites[] = {
    { "suit1", init_suite, clean_suite, setup_suite, teardown_suite, test_array1},
    { "suit2", init_suite, clean_suite, setup_suite, teardown_suite, test_array2},
    CU_SUITE_INFO_NULL,
};
```

IMO, they should have maintained the interface compatibility on a 2.1 minor release. But it was a change made 9 years ago. Also note that the document website is out-of-dated regarding to the interface change of `CU_SuiteInfo`.

Answer (score 0):

The signature of setup_suite and teardown_suite must be:

```c
void setup_suite(void) { return; }
void teardown_suite(void) { return; }
```